# Convert textarea value to something suitable for span

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have data taken from a textarea and put into a database. It is then returned from the database, and I want to put it into a span tag with the formatting still intact. Is there a method that does this? I have tried

```
.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
```

which fixes the line breaks, but that still leaves the whitespace and.. I am sure there has to be a built-in method somewhere.

Comment: What whitespace are you referring to?

Comment: As in, pressing the spacebar multiple times leaves a gap between characters which seems to be removed when I put it into a span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution is to mark your span as pre-formatted:

```
<span style="white-space:pre">text from textarea here</span>
```

Comment: An alternative, although inferior, solution, is to replace spaces with "&nbsp;".

Comment: Why don't you like this answer?

Comment: Because not even this website uses the pre tag when formatting the code in the questions/answers.

Comment: James, if you want to put the replaceing whitespace with &nbsp; as the answer.. I will tick it (can't create answers myself).

Comment: OK so the answer to your question is "no, there isn't a built in method." At least not one that's good enough.

Comment: @James how come when I inspect the html in firefox, I see no pre tags and all <br> &nbsp; instead?

Comment: Which part of the page are you looking at? I'm looking at the HTML for Tim's answer, and I see the following: `<pre><code>&lt;span style="white-space:pre"&gt;text from textarea here&lt;/span&gt;
</code></pre>`

Comment: Hmm must have missed that. Well, facebook doesn't use pre in their wall posts :)